# ASP.NET MVC3 , Why we need strongly-typed View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have read Scott Guthrie's Blog - [ASP.NET MVC 3: New @model keyword in Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx)

One things i don't realizes is a page will binding value in different ways,but why we have to enforce the view binding from Model?

For example, a user control panel of forum website, it may have the user information, the post history, the user setting etc.

From the view of data model, the binding source can be come from different table : users, posts, user_settings etc.

However, one view only can reference one @model directive.

Actually ,i can add what properties to model that i have to use.
So what is the advantage of make the view became strongly-typed?

Comment: What is exactly the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, one view only can reference one @model directive.

Yes, and this should be your view model. A view model is a class that you specifically design to meet the requirements of a given view. And you do this for each view

> From the view of data model, the binding source can be come from
>   different table : users, posts, user_settings etc.

Great, then design a view model that will contain all the necessary properties and have the controller build this view model aggregating the information from the different places and pass it to the view for displaying.

You should never pass your domain models to your views. Because views are normally the projection of one or more domain models => thus the need to define a view model.

Comment: I read yours and Rhapsody's answer, thanks you very much.(SOF don't let me mark two as answers..)
In additional, i search more info about ViewModel and find some interesting about MVVM - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel.

Comment: @SilverNight, MVVM is a design pattern more commonly used in WPF, Silverlight and WP7. In it the view model interacts with the domain model. This pattern is not suitable for ASP.NET MVC where the view model shouldn't know anything about the domain model. In ASP.NET MVC its the controller that's responsible to perform the coordination between the different domain models and the view model. In MVVM there's no Controller.

Comment: Phil Haack calls these 'view-specific models' in *Professional ASP.Net MVC3* - precisely because of the potential for confusion with WPF MVVM. They aren't really the same thing, although they serve a similar purpose.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can use automatic [scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/)

2) IntelliSense support

3) Compile time type checking

Answer (score 2):

Your view model should be decoupled from your business models.

A single page will have a single **view** model.

For example:

```
public class UserPost
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Your UserName property will be coming from the Users table and the UserName field in it. 
Your Subject might be coming from a Subjects table and the Messages from another one.

Your view should be concerned only with *presenting* already processed information, and not querying data sources.

Answer (score 1):

Therefore it is best practice to create a ViewModel per View. This ViewModel contains all properties needed by the view (users, post, settings etc).

In the controller/model you can instantiate the ViewModel and fill its properties. So don't supply a single table/list of records to a view, but a ViewModel.

The advantage is that, with everything strongly typed, there's less chance on runtime errors. Further, when something changes (i.e. database columns), these errors will be detected by the IDE directly.